# Autoscrolling in Xamarin set to timer

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently working on a teleprompter app for a business in my area. I am trying to figure out how I can autoscroll at a set interval through all of the text with Xamarin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well:

- in OnAppearing set the prompter enabled
- on OnDisappearing set it to disabled
- would create a custom control (separate subject, many community blogs about it, [official docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj04MTam4_nAhUBx4sKHRpjBeIQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fxamarin%2Fxamarin-forms%2Fapp-fundamentals%2Fcustom-renderer%2Flistview)) consisting of a listview that would launch the scroll timer upon command. So your timer is inside your custom ListView control. The timer would execute in the UI tread (important) to scroll to appropriate position. Timer is easy:

  ```
              Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5), () =>
              {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                  // do your stuff, scroll etc

                });                       
                  return true; //reapeat (false = do not)
              });
  ```
- the scroll itsself is easy, have many question on SO regarding [how to scroll to an item in listview](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20scroll%20to%20an%20item%20in%20listview%20site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Stupid question, how would I setup the method? Would it be a boolean?

Comment: Yes You can create a property in the control and react to its change by the ViewModel, for example in override OnPropertyChanged launching timer when your custom-created property Running is true..